# Print lines that are not numbers

Tags: regex, csv, awk, sed, grep

Quite simply, I have a csv file, with one column that should only contain integers. However, not all of them are integers, and I want to check this file (over 5 gigabytes large) and to capture the line numbers and (preferably) the values that are not integers. I've tried a number of things, such as using masks, but to no avail.

For example, we have the following csv table:

```
ID
5342
76375
sdfg23
2342lslf
jfijfojwo
395-34425
abc-24523
afhfhue3224
```

I would want to know that lines 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8 are not integers. Output would look like (as a dataframe/table equivalent):

```
+-------------+------+
| ID          | Row  |
+-------------+------+
| sdfg23      | 3    |
| 2342lslf    | 4    |
| jfijfojwo   | 5    |
| 395-34425   | 6    |
| abc-24523   | 7    |
| afhfhue3224 | 8    |
+-------------+------+
```

Or even just spilling the line numbers to standard out would be really helpful.

I've tried things like using `sed` for example: `sed -n '/?![[:digit:]]=' csvfile.csv`

Comment: a few sample lines (say 3-5), expected output for that and at least one command that you tried will go a long way in making your question clear and easier to answer

Comment: Sorry about that! I fixed it up, it should be much clearer now @Sundeep

Comment: `sed -n '/[^0-9]/p' file`?

Comment: `?!` is lookaround syntax, which isn't available in `sed` or `awk`.. and anyway you needed negated character class `[^[:digit:]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if any line contains any non-digit character.

```
$ # -n option enables line number in output
$ grep -n '[^0-9]' ip.txt
1:ID
4:sdfg23
5:2342lslf
6:jfijfojwo
7:395-34425
8:abc-24523
9:afhfhue3224
```

If you need further processing, `awk` would suit. Below is just an example, you can modify as per your needs.

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print "ID Row"; next} /[^0-9]/{print $0, NR-1}' ip.txt
ID Row
sdfg23 3
2342lslf 4
jfijfojwo 5
395-34425 6
abc-24523 7
afhfhue3224 8
```

Comment: If it turns out that the column has non-integers, but they are floats, is there an easy way to convert the column over to integers? Maybe with a python script?

Comment: you can use `int` function in `awk` too

Comment: I can ask a separate question for this, but it's in a file and I'm trying to clean up the columns using pandas and python... Perhaps I should just ask it, it seems like a good question.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `grep` to find all lines that are numeric and invert the result:

```
grep -vE '^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$' file
```

The `^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$` pattern (POSIX ERE syntax enabled with `-E`) matches lines that fully match `111` or `111.111111` like numbers and `-v` will invert the result.

See the [online `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/cclAii):

```
s="11.1111
5342
76375
sdfg23
2342lslf
jfijfojwo
395-34425
abc-24523
afhfhue3224"
grep -vE '^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
sdfg23
2342lslf
jfijfojwo
395-34425
abc-24523
afhfhue3224
```